# How does one loop through the tables of a database in ASP.NET (WebMatrix)?

Tags: asp.net, html, razor, webmatrix

SOLVED (my own problem):

`SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

This worked for me.

---

As following the tutorial on the Microsoft website [here](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/web-development-101-part-5-using-data#_Toc281081979), I've found it quite easy to loop through the rows of a table using the following code.

```
 @{
   var data = Database.Open("FullDatabase").Query("SELECT * FROM Servers");
 } 

<div id="movieslist">
    <ol>
        @foreach(var row in data)
        {
        <li><a href="#">@row.Item</a></li>
        }
    </ol>
</div>
```

Which outputs the following:

```
1. Virtual Machines

2. Physical Machines

3. Processors (CPU)

4. Memory (RAM)

5. OS Build
```

However, the "Servers" table is just one of many in the database. What I would love to do is something like this:

```
 @{
   var database = Database.Open("FullDatabase")
 } 

<div id="movieslist">
    <ol>
        @foreach(var table in database)
        {
        var data = database.Query("SELECT * FROM " + table);
            @foreach(var row in data)
            {
            <li><a href="#">@row.Item</a></li>
            }
         }
    </ol>
</div>
```

Is such a thing possible? If so how? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, that's just something you do for fun, and never, ever in production sites, as you should only retrieving what you really want, and not wast any more bandwidth / time consuming all the things you don't need.

Secondly, you can always query the system data and for get all tables to the board, you just issue a SELECT statement like:

```
SELECT name FROM [sysobjects] WHERE xtype = 'u';
```

or

```
SELECT name FROM [sys].[objects] WHERE type_desc = 'USER_TABLE';
```

or

```
SELECT table_name FROM [information_schema].[tables];
```

**They all do the same**, depending on what SQL Version you are using...

So your `database` query would look like:

```
var database = Database
                  .Open("FullDatabase")
                  .Query("SELECT name FROM [sysobjects] WHERE xtype = 'u'");
```

Comment: Could you please explain why this wouldn't be done in production sites? I am very new to server side development so information like this is quite valuable to me. I'm also not sure what you mean by only retrieving what I need as I will need each row from each table.

Comment: Each row, but what columns! In production and good developers never use the `*` (all) keyword, but rather specify the columns you want, *for example*, to list users, all you need would be `Id`, `Name`, `LastLoginTime` and nothing else, this prevents getting excess information from a Table where you need a connection to the database (normally other computer that hosts the database) and for that, more time to load... the other part is, you should always use paging for big amounts of rows, users never read more than 20 rows at once, and getting 20 rows at a time is way faster than hundreds...

Comment: what db version are you using? try to see if you have tho use the `sys.objects` convention instead `sysobjects`...

Comment: I found the solution - `SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`. Nonetheless thanks for all the help! :)

Comment: Man I gave you the tick because you were resilient with answering my query. I will definitely credit you in my work.